# Bluetooth Issues on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Kernel 5.19.0-42-generic

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, intel

The motherboard is a Gigabyte Aorus B550I itx board, checked the Gigabyte website Wifi+Bluetooth is supported by Intel AX200.

The problem with Bluetooth is say I connect a device like my earbuds or keyboard they get paired and work for a while(< 5min), but if I switch the devices or if they stay idle
then the devices get disconnected and don't get reconnected.
If I toggle Bluetooth off sometimes I get the message Airplane Mode needs to be turned off.

The same devices work fine on Windows 10, running in dual boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, funny story
My motherboard did come with antennas, I assumed they are needed only for Wifi, I just added those and boom the Bluetooth range has increased connection both on ubuntu and Windows are way more stable.
I also updated the BIOS to the latest version just to be safe.